# How to include only some of vimrc in ideavimrc

Tags: vim, ideavim

I know that I can use a `.ideavimrc` file, and from it I can source my `.vimrc`  But there are some settings in there that don't work well.

With vim I can do things like:

```
" Avoid installing twice or when in unsupported Vim version.
if (v:version > 700)
    " do some set up
endif
```

Does anyone know if I can do something similar so that ideavimrc will just skip certain sections?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, if this is up to date. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-669#comment=27-1103675 https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdeaVIM now supports this syntax. Wrap the lines you want to make conditional in your `~/.vimrc` like this:

```
if !has("ide")
  "Settings to hide from IdeaVIM go here
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

IdeaVim doesn't support if-statements in Vim scripts.

As a workaround, consider creating a file with common stuff that is included into both ~/.vimrc and ~/.ideavimrc:

~/.vim/common.vim:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
...
```

~/.vimrc:

```
if something
    source ~/.vim/common.vim
endif
```

~/.ideavimrc:

```
source ~/.vim/common.vim
```

Comment: Down-voting because the premise of this answer is no longer true. IdeaVIM now does support if statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can trick IdeaVim into skipping things in .vimrc. For example:

`source ./.bundles.vim` works both in vim and ideavim, whereas `exec "source ~/.bundles.vim"` is only picked up by vim.